# <c:if test=""> doesn't work

Tags: jstl

I'm new to JSTL and for some reason, I can't get the test line to work. Here is the simplified code I'm using:

```
<c:if test="${hasChild}">
      test 
</c:if>
```

when I use

> ${hasChild}

it prints true to the screen but it doesn't woork on the test line and I don't know why. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Have you declared **hasChild** prior to the test taking place? i.e.

```
<c:set var="hasChild">*Something which makes this value true*</c:set>
<c:if test="${hasChild}">
  test 
</c:if>
```